# $G= \langle w,H \rangle$, prove that $[G:H]=2$

Tags: group-theory

let $G= \langle w,H \rangle$, where $w\in G-H, w^2=1, H < G$, $wHw^{-1}=H$. prove that $[G:H]=2$ .

I know that $G= \{e,w,H,wH,Hw\} = \{H,wH\}$.

Since $G ≠ H, [G:H]>1$.

Since $|G| \le |H|+|wH|=2|H|$, $[G:H] \le 2$

So it follows that $[G:H]=2$

Is it true or am I missing something?

EDIT:
This it the source of the question: (it's in Hebrew so that's why i didn't upload it)
[image]

Comment: Your notations are all over the place.

Comment: I'm pretty new in it... sorry

Comment: Where is your question from?

Comment: From an exam at the University

Comment: Could you upload a picture of your question?

Comment: It's not in english

Comment: @user7080065 which language is it in? I can help you translate it if I know the language.

Comment: Is this an active exam?

Comment: Of course not!! from 8 years ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire trick to this question lies in your first step.  Once you know that $G=H\cup wH$ and $H\not=wH$, then the result follows directly.

In particular, since the index is the number of left cosets, and the only two left cosets are $eH$ and $wH$, the index is $2$.

Your approach works, provided $G$ and $H$ are finite groups (otherwise, you can't write down $|G|$ and $|H|$).

The proof that $G=H\cup wH$ is missing in the question statement, how did you prove this (it is true, but might take a few lines to prove).